# Unmarshall both flat and nested jsons in golang

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

Say I want to be able to handle both nested and unnested `json`s of the following form, as in this example:

```
source_json_1 := `{"owner": "John", "nickname": "Rose", "species": "Dog"}`
source_json_2 := `{"owner": "Doe", "Pet": [{"nickname": "Rose", "species": "Dog"},
                                          {"nickname": "Max", "species": "Cat"}]}`
```

If I define `Pet` as an embedded struct I can easily unmarshal it with:

```
type Owner struct {
    Name string
    Pet
}

type Pet struct {
    NickName    string
    Species     string
}
```

Resulting in John's pet getting adequately marshalled.

```
{John {Rose Dog}}
{Doe { }}
```

But since `Pet` can actually also be a slice of `Pet`s, Doe's `Pet`s are not correctly unmarshalled. If instead go with

```
type Owner struct {
    Name string
    Pet  []Pet
}
```

Then Doe gets marshalled just fine.

```
{John []}
{Doe [{Rose Dog} {Max Cat}]}
```

How can I catch both cases?

I'd prefer to marshall it into a slice of `Pet`s in the end, no matter what.

Comment: Pet is embedded, but it is not anonymous - it's named Pet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at two separate data structures, so to unmarshal them with a single `struct` type, you'd need to account for both:

```
type Owner struct {
    Name string
    Pet
    Pets []Pet `json:"Pet"`
}
```

Then, if you want the slice to be authoritative, after you unmarshall, move the embedded to the slice:

```
// owner := unmarshall blah blah
if owner.Pet != Pet{} {
    owner.Pets = append(owner.Pets, owner.Pet)
}
```

Comment: Ideally, if you can control the program generating the JSON, just use the array annotation exclusively.  If the owner only has one pet, then the array only has a single entry, but it's still an array.  No reason to have two separate structures to convey the same information when they are not actually logically distinct situations.

Comment: Agreed. My assumption was that the incoming data was outside their control.

Comment: Agree fully, I was looking for a more general pattern to handle denormalized data that needs to be normalized before it goes into a database. The above pattern is elegant